# Ability to show a indicator next to a field if it is changed

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

Is there any possiblity that if I make any changes after saving the record,there a provision to indicate that this field has been changed like a indicator or so.But I would have to see the changed value also.

I searched some articles and I was recommended to use a formulae field showing indicator but I want the formulae to be used by default.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of doing that in a standard layout (next to the field). You would need either to create your own visualforce page to see the record and its fields, or add a component to the record's standard layout, which would show the field changes (those can be tracked by a trigger, for example).

If you don't need to do this right next to the field, you can turn on "Track Field History". You'll get a related list-like component on the record page that shows the changes made to the fields (the list won't be turned on automatically if your object is already created. It will be available in the layout editor page. Also, the fields won't be tracked automatically either. In the object's page there will be a `Set History Tracking` button for you to select which fields are going to be tracked).

Comment: Thanks @renato. I understand that we can do this by history tracking but I wanted it to show next to the field

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on field history tracking for up to 20 fields on an object.  This will show the changes that have been made to a field and who made them.  This feature does not provide an indicator next to the field itself.

You can read more about field history tracking here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en

Comment: Thanks @jagular. I understand that we can do this by history tracking but I wanted it to show next to the field